# Why new users on CentOS 7 don't have /usr/local/bin in their PATH?

Tags: centos, users, path

I install a program in a form of a binary(docker-compose) in /usr/local/bin which is expected to be the most correct way. I expect that all users can now use it. I add a new user with Ansible `user` module. But for new users the program does not work at all because /usr/local/bin is not in their PATH. **WHY** it's not there? What did I do wrong? Did I create a user in a wrong way? Why isn't `/usr/local/bin` in PATH by default for other users? I don't know where with directory is added to PATH in my own user where it works. It's not in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`

Comment: This question might give you an idea: https://serverfault.com/questions/833762/where-does-the-bash-path-on-centos-7-get-usr-local-bin-from#838000 if /usr/local/bin/ was indeed hardcoded in CentOS builds of bash and sshd (why they would do this is beyond me?!), perhaps that is now removed, and the path was never added back to /etc/profile after it was removed from the binaries. I’m just guessing here.

Comment: @RoubenTchakhmakhtchian What should I do? Manually add it to PATH for all users I create? I just feels like it should already be there. If it isn't then I am using the system in a wrong way. The system is bound to work correctly.

Comment: Try adding it to /etc/profile, that should affect all users.

Comment: @RoubenTchakhmakhtchian Now it's doesn't work with sudo because `/etc/sudoers` also has its opinion on PATH. And it also doesn't contain `/usr/local/bin`. Why? So `/usr/local/bin` is not safe? I try to do everything in a recommended way but always end up doing unsafe stuff. Was /usr/local/bin actually correct for software installations?

Comment: Red Hat has some ideas about what is considered safe and what isn’t. That’s why /usr/local/bin isn’t in the sudoers path. It’s up to the admins of the system to add the path by putting a file in /etc/profile.d/.

Comment: @jsbillings I just want to know what is a safe way to install `docker-compose` according to Red Hat. If I can't use `usr/local/bin` then how else? I am following vendor's docs

Comment: You should install docker-compose via EPEL. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: Please confirm you've got no output for this command:

`strings /bin/bash | grep "\/usr\/local\/bin"`